# How to map JSON object from axios onto an array in react

Tags: json, reactjs, axios, response, typeerror

Im new to react and im trying to do a simple axios request to an api and display the data in a list.[Code of my pokemon component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKm4c.png)

I have done the request successfully and can log an object of cards. But it is in the render method that it is saying
TypeError: this.state.pokemons.map is not a function

[Error in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XG5hy.png)

I have used axios before and followed this with JSONplaceholder. But im not sure why it is not working now? I have looked around and found it may be because im returning an object which does not have access to the .map() function. But i do not know the solution.

Here is the code from the browser console 
[Browser console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DW1YW.png)

[Browser console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ma2Xd.png)

[Browser console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNSSj.png)

Any help would be amazing! Thank you!

This is my first post, sorry if its not all formatted right!

Comment: As I can see from  from the API result, you are getting a JSON with property `cards`, so try to set the state like `this.setState({pokemons: res.data.cards})`

Comment: Can you please share the code directly in your Post? Makes it easier to develop solutions. You can mark it with three backticks (```) or by indenting four spaces as code.

Comment: Please also post the return data from the request. The one you used the console log in the componentDidMount function.

Comment: Hi! It worked by adding res.data.cards! Thanks so much :)